# How do i handle multipart file upload in spring 2.5 with java 1.4 (with out anotation)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

How do i handle multipart file upload in spring 2.5 with java 1.4 (with out anotation)?

I need to handle the request in

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

}
```

/////

```
<form action="tradeshowinfo.htm?type=save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Event Start Date:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="eventStart" id="eventStart"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Event End Date:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="eventEnd" id="eventEnd"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Location:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="location"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Description:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea type="text" name="description"> </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Image:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="image"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Link:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea type="text" name="url"> </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: that is where i m stuck
i can't use parameterized types any where in java 1.4

Comment: googles it and all the solution is through annotation or for java 1.5+

Comment: See whatever solution you get in java1.5 can be converted to java1.4.. Have you tried this

Comment: I have tried and one of the problem is  parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5

Comment: Post the code here for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example here :  http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/
and convert Java1.5 dependencies to Java 1.4

Comment: getting this error 

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteRequestFacade cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest

at this line 

MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;

Comment: I found another example http://www.roseindia.net/spring/springfileuploadexample.shtml